# WPF cannot dock control in a dock panel, canvas seems to instead get centered

Tags: wpf

When using the xaml markup

```xml
<Window x:Class="Foo.Bar.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="400" Width="400">
    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True">
        <Canvas DockPanel.Dock="Right" Width="100" />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

...it seems like the canvas does not get docked to the right.

Why?

Instead it becomes centered.

[image]

Comment: `LastChildFill` is set to `true`. As your `DockPanel` only has one child, it is also the _last_ child, so it is being set to `Fill`.

Comment: Ok, but how does that translate to `Center`?

Comment: Also, removing `LastChildFill` does not change anything.

Comment: You overrode the automatic width selection by explicitly setting it to `100`. Since it couldn't actually fill with that rule, it did the best it could and centered it.

Comment: Let me do some quick tests and get back to you...  I would have expected it to dock to the right when `LastChildFill` is `false`.

Comment: I managed to solve this confusion when I removed the Width setting, but maybe I am set!

Comment: It looks like `LastChildFill` is set to `true` by default, so simply removing it would have no effect.  If you don't want this behavior, you will have to explicitly set `LastChildFill` to `false`.  You _should_ be able to keep the width explicit width if you set last child to false.

Comment: Maybe my question is too confused to keep. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have [`LastChildFill`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.dockpanel.lastchildfill) set to `true`. As your `DockPanel` only has *one* child, it is also the *last* child, so it is being overridden to `Fill`.  The reason it is getting centered is that the `Width` has been explicitly set to `100`. Since it can't fill with that override, it does the best it can, and centers it.

Simply removing `LastChildFill` will not fix the issue, as the default value is `true`. To fix this, you will have to explicitly set `LastChildFill` to `false`.

The reason for these default settings is that `DockPanel` is *usually* used to house multiple child controls, where the children docked to different sides are listed first, and the final child takes up the remaining area. Using it with only a single child is fairly unusual.